# Angularjs $scope - how to get correct one via controller (beginner)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have problem with understanding how to show/hide element on page using controller.

There is a code with an example - you can check it by clicking "close edit" button (nothing happen):

```js
var appModule = angular.module('appModule', []);

appModule.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    $scope.closeEdit = function(index, newValue) {
      $scope.isEditing = false; // here I would like to close editing option but it doesn't work
      //$scope.items[index] = newValue; // in next step I would like to update "item" value with new one but it doesn't work correctly
    };
  }
]);
```

```css
table td:first-child,
input {
  width: 100px;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>
      <div>
        <span ng-hide="isEditing"> <!-- should hide when editing and update after it with new value  -->
                    {{item}}
                </span>

        <input ng-show="isEditing" type="text" ng-model="newValue" placeholder="{{item}}" />
        <!-- should show when editing  -->
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button ng-hide="isEditing" ng-click="isEditing = !isEditing">OPEN EDIT</button>
      <!-- should hide when editing  -->
      <button ng-show="isEditing" ng-click="closeEdit($index, newValue)">close edit</button>
      <!-- should show when editing  -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change value "isEditing" via controller. There is no problem to do it via HTML like that

```
ng-click="isEditing = !isEditing"
```

But code below doesn't work correctly in controller:

```
$scope.isEditing = false;
```

The purpose of it is to show/hide buttons/fields to provide new values.

After that probably there will be problem with update new values.

If you can explain - thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `ng-repeat` create new child scope and you are changing `isEditing` variable in that scope. To fix it specify controller in assignment:

```
ng-click="appCtrl.isEditing = !appCtrl.isEditing"
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a62bny1/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried also add new controller to ng-repeat, and it's also works: `<tr ng-repeat="item in items" ng-controller="controlerInNgRepeat">`